# Reactjs resize from sides or top of box? Maybe with jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a div I want to resize in reactjs. I dont want to use the lower right resize part. I like jquery ui resizable where I can specify north, south, east, west. Is it possible to use jquery ui resizable react or is there some alternative that does the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

In general you want to avoid using jQuery with React as they both change the DOM. This could result in some nasty bugs or generally hacky code. There's a bunch of plugins and tools that are have been created for React. Some time on google will give you a bunch of results.

I'm not too sure what you mean by specifying north, west, etc.. this might be a good starting point: https://github.com/STRML/react-resizable

Comment: This is the problem... I don't want to use the handle, I want to use the sides.

Comment: This is a starting point. You can review the code to see how react-resizable works and then extend to include the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

To mix jQuery UI or any other dom generator like ExtJs into React is definitely not the way to go.

The way react is working is not compatible with this frameworks, because React is re-rendering the whole virtual dom on every change, and patching differences to it. And the fancy resizable html, which was generated by jQuery UI would disappear/break on every react re-rendering

You should consider some of the React Components, which you can use, and bring your support to the eco-system by testing, and improving. I am sure, there will be very soon some really good layout components for React, maybe already there, but not well known like jquery ui or extjs. Just try some of them:

https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

https://strml.github.io/react-resizable

Remember, it's open source, so you are allowed to modify this software, and make it better. It would be awesome if you could post your modifications and share it with others